# Как транслировать видео по расписанию на сайте?

Tags: php, flash, видео, online-video, schedule

Здраствуйте!
Подскажите как реализовать трансцяцию видео по расписанию?(аналог ТВ). На сервере будут храниться несколько видеофайлов их нужно транслировать на сайт в определённое время, желательно еще с возможность ставить видео в очередь. Какими технологиями это можно реализовать? Может у кого то есть готовое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение "на коленке":
Вы знаете начало старта (время x) и продолжительность каждого видео.
С помощью простых мат. операций вы можете определить можно ли "транслироваьт видео". Далее выставить какое видео и какое время на нем выставить, с помощью js

```
var vid = document.getElementById("yourVideo");
vid.currentTime = 5;
```

У самого тега *video* выставляете

```
<video autoplay...>...</video>
```

controls не выставляете, можно сделать свои элементы управления, в частности звука.

Если пользователь загрузил страницу до начала "трансляции", то с помощью js можно обновить страницу при наступлении времени x, либо обновить контент через ajax

***UPD**

Так сделать не получится.
Если есть php то при загрузки страницы можно сверять текущее время и время с которого можно начинать трансляцию:

`$timeToStart = 17; // с 17 часов можно запускать
 $currentTime = (int)date('G');
If($currentTime >= $timeToStart) {
echo '<video autoplay src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>';
}`

Comment: Я не сильна в js, подскажите, что в этом коде не так?: `var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

var currentTime = new Date(),
    targetTime = new Date('YYYY/MM/DD 12:45');

setTimeout(function () {
    vid.autoplay=true;
}, targetTime - currentTime);`

Comment: Скажите, чего вы хотели добиться этим? 
Тогда я смогу вам более подробно подсказать.

Comment: Начать транслировать видео в указанное время `targetTime = new Date('YYYY/MM/DD 12:45');`, но видео сразу начинает транслироватся. Не могу понять как правильно произвести мат. операцию по вычислению времени старта видео.

Comment: Написал в апдейте к ответу

Comment: Да, можно  сделать и на php, но как быть с прокруткой видео до определённого момента? Например если видео началось в 17:00, а пользователь зашел на сайт в 17:20, тогда он должен смотреть видео начиная с 20-той минуты, как это реализовать?

Comment: Тогда, также высчитываете какое время прошло от 17 часов. Также с помощью date().
И вот тут, уже подключаете к работе JS

`<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("yourVideo");
vid.currentTime = "<?php echo $elapsedTime?>";
</script>`

Ровно таким же макаром, вычисляете какое видео ставить.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, удалось сделать на чистом js. Эдинственная проблема осталась в том что Google Chorm не устанавливает значение currentTime. В остальных браузерах всё работает.